# ABD information and assistance with statistical information

Tags: all-but-dissertation

I am presently in a PhD program and was an ABD student. I am curious as to the following information, which will also assist me in formulating my dissertation topic:
1. How many students are ABD on this site?
2. How did many of you end up in an ABD status?
3. How many ABD students are searching for ways to complete their degree?
4. What opportunities have you found that will assist you with your degree completion?
I hope to help as many ABDs as possible and I would appreciate it if you could help me by responding to these questions. Please feel free to ask me any questions as well.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. I think your question is not a great fit for our question-and-answer site (and is indeed not considered [on topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ). You might try Reddit...though, frankly, it seems like you would require a scientifically-validated survey rather than just asking some random folks online.

Comment: Polling like this is generally not allowed on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: And ABD means ? All But Done?

Comment: I believe it means 'all but dissertation'.

Answer (score 1):

I was never ABD.  Datapoint to help your survey.